# onKeyDown not being trigged when using arrow keys

Tags: javascript

My checkKey() function is not being trigged whenever I use arrow keys, please help.

Function ckeckKey():

```
        function checkKey(e) {
            var event = window.event ? window.event : e;
            if (event.keyCode==38) {
                go_north();
            }
            if (event.keyCode==39) {
                go_east();
            }
            if (event.keyCode==40) {
                go_south();
            }
            if (event.keyCode==37) {
                go_west();
            }
        }
```

Trigger:

```
    <input id="controller" type="textbox" onKeyDown="checkKey(event);" />
```

It was working before and now it just stopped working.

EDIT: I decided to use WASD keys instead.

Comment: Why do you use `if(true)`?

Comment: Removed it from my code.

Comment: Debug protip: `console.log(e)` before the variable `event` is set

Comment: _'It was working before and now it just stopped working'_ what change was made when it stopped working?

Comment: Not sure, but when I did console.log I got `'KeyboardEvent.keyLocation' is deprecated. Please use 'KeyboardEvent.location' instead. VM1912:437
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. VM1912:437
KeyboardEvent {altGraphKey: false, repeat: false, metaKey: false, altKey: false, shiftKey: false…}
 game.html:245
KeyboardEvent {altGraphKey: false, repeat: false, metaKey: false, altKey: false, shiftKey: false…}
 `

Comment: is checkKey in the global scope?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: is the function defined in another function or object, ie `function som(){ function checkKey(){} }` or globally ie `<script>function checkKey(){}</script>` if it is not global it wont be visible to the input so it cannot be executed.

Comment: Its a global function. EDIT: Also clicking other keys works.